# Flutter iOS app is not asking for notification permissions

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The iOS app I made with Flutter does not ask for notification permissions.

It wanted it in the first version of the app, but now it doesn't.

iOS device settings:

[image: iOS device setting]

Apple developer console:

[image: Apple developer console]

I am using [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) for notifications. When I did research on the subject, I saw that it was related to certificates, but I could not understand it. I have not made such a setting for Flutter before.

---

**Fixed**

I found the problem. I made a mistake where I asked for notification permission. [Flutter Firebase permission](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/permissions/).

It got resolved when I followed the directive on this page again.

Comment: Did you add push notification capability in Xcode?

Comment: yes, i did. push notification and background mode

Comment: Ok I understand. Did you call requestNotificationPermissions?

Comment: Can you confirm in general your code follows the provided docs?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71890309/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: The bounty is a bit dodgy. Why would you sacrifice half of your reputation points on such a question? A [DenverCoder9](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients) situation?